# About javascript object property assignment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The `const person = { address }` object property assignment that is equivalent to `const x = { address: address }`, and I'm well aware that is not possible to assign a property like this `const person = { adress.street }`, but what I want to know is the why behind the "you can't". Why javascript don't `const person = { 'adress.street': address.street }`. What javascript is doing behind the scenes?

Comment: [ECMA-262 -> 12.2.6 Object Initializer](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-initializer)

Comment: Actually [you can](https://github.com/rbuckton/proposal-shorthand-improvements/blob/master/README.md) (in the future, maybe)

Comment: @JonasWilms That's great!  I'll add that link to my answer, if you don't have any objections.

Comment: @amy I don't own TC39, so ... ;)

Comment: @JonasWilms Fair enough.  I asked in case you had plans to write your own answer.  I didn't want to steal any thunder or step on any toes.

Comment: @amy these are *my* internetpoints! Gimme tem back! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's how its defined in the [EcmaScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-initializer).  This "shorthand property" syntax was introduced in ES2015.

An object literal is composed of a `PropertyDefinitionList`, which is itself defined in terms of `PropertyDefinition`s.

A property definition is defined as:

- An identifier (this is the so-called "shorthand syntax" you're asking about)
- Property name `:` Assignment expression
- other things that aren't relevant to the question

In your question, `adress.stree` is not an identifier; it is an expression composed of two identifiers joined by a member access operator.  Thus it does not fit the specification and cannot be used in the shorthand syntax.

A [TC39 proposal](https://github.com/rbuckton/proposal-shorthand-improvements/blob/master/README.md) exists to extend the syntax even further, giving you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with a function.

```js
function setObjectProperty(object, property, value) {
  var props = property.split(".");
  var obj = object;
  for (let i = 0; i < props.length - 1; i++) {
    const prop = props[i];
    if (prop in obj && typeof obj[prop] == "object") {
      obj = obj[prop];
    } else {
      obj = obj[props[i]] = {};
    }
  }
  obj[props[props.length - 1]] = value;
}

//# Usage

const person = {};
setObjectProperty(person,"address.street","Fatih Sultan Mehmet Cad.");
setObjectProperty(person,"address.city","Konya");
setObjectProperty(person,"country.name","Türkiye");
setObjectProperty(person,"country.short","TR");
console.log(person);
```